# How to manage pytests’ `tests` folder name collision with jupyter extensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytest, python-import, importerror

I’m in the process of writing unit tests for my software.

I wrote some helpers for my tests. For convenience I would like to use them in a `jupyter notebook`.

When I try to import them inside of the notebook though, I get an error.

```
from tests import helpers
```

->

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d8ba72c24738> in <module>
----> 1 from tests.helpers import some_helper

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.helpers'
```

Digging a little, I found out that importing `tests` actually imports this folder as a module:

```
 '/my_project_path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions/tests'
```

The folder contains `test_autoreload.py` and `test_storemagic.py`, which are tests for extensions I use.

**Here’s my question, how do I properly manage this conflict?** I would like to keep those extension installed, and I would like to keep the name `tests` for my folder, as it is the convention when working with `pytest`.

I installed those extensions with `pip`. Did I miss an option to ignore the tests when installing or something?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but some hints here in case they help you:

I was having the same issue today and getting a bit crazy. Not in `jupyter` but int the `ipyton` shell. As `jupyter` uses `ipython` I guess it will be the same issue.

IPython has a module called [tests](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/IPython/extensions/tests)
within the `IPython/extensions` folder, and this folder is added is added to the search path when using `ipython` instead of `python`.

This are my paths from a `python` shell (using `sys.path`):

```
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

And the ones from an `ipython` shell:

```
['/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/dmontaner/.ipython']
```

So, if your are in `iptyhon` or in a notebook and you `import tests` or `from tests import something`, the interpreter will search in:

```
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions'
```

So far all is as expected. But I also had as you my own `tests` module in the same directory where my `ipython` session was running. What should happen then is that my own `tests` module should be imported first. But it was not and I had the same error as you.

If I would remove the 'IPython/extensions' from the path doing `sys.path.remove(.../IPython/extensions')` then I was able to import my own module.

I did uninstall `ipyton` and `ipython_genutils` and, using `python -m pytest` in the command line (on a .py file, not a notebook) I was still having a slightly similar issue this time about `dash` trying to load the IPython. The weird thing is that in my project I am not using `dash` but flask and `dash` is not a dependency of pytest anyway I think.

So, I uninstalled `ipyton`, `ipython_genutils`, `dash` and `plotly` and then I could run `pytest` importing from my own tests module.

I reinstalled the 4 libraries again and the problem was solved! And now I can import from my tests module even from within a jupyter notebook.

I guess the message is that there is some buggy setup or dependency among all those libraries (and may be some others). Try to reinstall latest versions or recreate your virtual environment in case it helps.

Sorry that I could not figure out what was the exact problem... but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I also removed the […]/extensions from my path in the meantime, but it didn't feel like a very satisfactory method :)

I will try to recreate a clean venv and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The long-term fix for these kind of naming conflicts is to put all your code, including your test code, into a project package, such that you imports look like

`import my_project.tests.helpers` instead of `import tests.helpers`.

By choosing a unique name for your project, you define your own namespace and avoid naming conflicts.